# Overflow of integer calculation in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, integer-overflow

Please check the following snippet:

```
  unsigned char a = 100;
  unsigned char b = 100;
  unsigned char c = 100;
  unsigned short x = a * b + c;
```

I expected this would overflow and the calculation would be done in 8-bit type unsigned char (not in 16-bit unsigned short), exceeding the value range of unsigned char. But it doesn't.

Why does the calculation not overflow in C and C++?

Comment: Because the integral types get promoted to `int` before the calculation? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [...] arithmetic operators **do not accept types smaller than int** as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion

So your code behaves like this:

```
unsigned char a = (unsigned char)100;
unsigned char b = (unsigned char)100;
unsigned char c = (unsigned char)100;
unsigned short x = (unsigned short)((int)a * (int)b + (int)c);
```